# Getting post installation script to run for a module

Tags: joomla-3.x, module, development

I've a module that I want to run a script post installation, post update etc.

I think this can be done by adding a script.php into the module zip file and then calling it in the installation file.

```
<scriptfile>script.php</scriptfile>
```

in the xml file to set up the script.

In the script.php I've some test type stuff:

```
            <?php
            // No direct access to this file
            defined('_JEXEC') or die;

            /**
             * Script file of HelloWorld module
             */
            class mod_W4cAccordionDisplayInstallerScript
            {

                /**
                 * Method to install the extension
                 * $parent is the class calling this method
                 *
                 * @return void
                 */
                function install($parent) 
                {
                    echo '<p>The module has been installed</p>';
                            $db = JFactory::getDbo();
                    $query = $db->getQuery(true)
                            ->update('#__update_sites')
                            ->set('extra_query = "ids=12354"')
                            ->where('name = "Accordian Display"');
                    $db->setQuery($query);

                    $db->execute();

                }

                /**
                 * Method to uninstall the extension
                 * $parent is the class calling this method
                 *
                 * @return void
                 */
                function uninstall($parent)
```

I haven't copied the whole file since it's basically a copy of the joomla example.

When I run this by updating in the update then it says installation complete but it doesn't adjust the update sites table.

Any ideas where I might be going wrong

---

So I've now changed out the database update for

mail("myemail@gmail.com","My subject","user id is: ");

and put it into 
        function postflight($type, $parent)

but there is no email response - I think that it's not loading and running the 
 script :(

---

Figured it out - I had the wrong class name.  I had removed all the _ characters like you normally do for class names but apparently you don't for this script.  Hope this helps someone else.  Thanks for the thoughts.

Comment: Are you sure the class is correct in accordance with your module name?

Comment: module is mod_W4c_Accordion_Display

Comment: In the query there is a misspelling of the table field (at ->where) name Accordian instead of Accordion, maybe...

Comment: @ Zollie - I checked and the module name is spelt that way Accordian Display

Comment: Please would you mind writing your solution as a proper answer below and mark it as accepted. Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I changed the script to

```
            <?php
            // No direct access to this file
            defined('_JEXEC') or die;

            /**
             * Script file of HelloWorld module
             */
            class mod_w4c_accordion_displayInstallerScript
            {

                /**
                 * Method to install the extension
                 * $parent is the class calling this method
                 *
                 * @return void
                 */
```

The key to success was NOT removing the underscores - something you do with other areas of Joomla like in a helper.php file.  Once I'd done this it worked without a problem.

Answer (score 0):

On update, you should use the update method like

```
function update($parent) 
{
    // on update stuff
}
```

You can find it in Joomla documentation [Creating the extension script file](https://docs.joomla.org/J3.x:Creating_a_simple_module/Adding_an_install-uninstall-update_script_file)

Hope it helps.